# Delete data using a POST request in Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

It seems to me that it is feasible to use a `POST` request to delete data in Tornado from database:

```
def post(self, id):
    # delete data from db using id
```

And on the client side, we can send a post request with the desired `id` for which content to be deleted. Is this a valid approach?

I notice that there is also a `delete` method in RequestHandler class in Tornado, but how should I use it properly? Some example would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless i'm looking at an outdated exmplae it looks like tornado supports delete requests. http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html

I would use the `delete` method just like you'd use anything.  Set up handler with the delete method (probably specifying and `id`) then delete that record if it exist and if user has appropriate permissions.  I've never used Tornado but perhaps something like:

```
class WidgetHandler(RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, database):
        self.database = database    

    def delete(self, id):
        # if user has permission to delete
        # if record exists
        # delete it

app = Application([
    (r'/widgets/([0-9]+)', WidgetHandler, dict(database=database)),
    ])
```

If you are using javascript/jquery/ajax on the front to make the request the jquery ajax supports delete:

```
// get your id somehow
// dynamically build url   
$.ajax({
    url: '/widgets/' + theIdYouGotSomehow,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

For your comment, you can just hit the url with the delete method. `/widgets/12`

From jquery documentation they say

> but they [delete, put, etc] are not supported by all browsers.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Some stackoverflow posts suggest all modern browsers support the delete method.

Comment: thanks. Two questions on the front-end part: 1. how do I specify the `id` to be deleted in the JQuery `ajax` function? 2. is 'DELETE' supported by all the browsers?